# Getting Laravel 4 to validate application/vnd.ms-office

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4, mime-types

In my application, a user can upload a file of a few specific types, one of which needs to be a supposedly older excel file type `application/vnd.ms-office`.

I have `mime:xls,doc,csv` but those don't validate against mime type `application/vnd.ms-office`.

I've look around a few other places and making the validator rule `mime:xls,doc,csv,application/vnd.ms-office` does not work.

I can get it to work if I edit `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeExtensionGuesser` to contain `'application/vnd.ms-office' => 'office'` and adjust the validator rule to `mime:xls,doc,csv,office` but I I'll lose that the next time I update via composer.

Any way to manipulate the mime types array on-the-fly?

Also, `application/vnd.ms-office` seems like it might include a broad spectrum of files. Should I even allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I've managed to get the results I'm looking for by using a custom validator as such.

If I get no better answers after a while I'll mark this as the correct answer.

top of the class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
```

inside the post function:

```
Validator::extend('uploadable', function($attr, $file, $params)
{
    return $file instanceof UploadedFile
        && in_array($file->getMimeType(), array(
            'application/msword',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'application/pdf',
            'text/html',
            'text/rtf',
            'text/csv',
            'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
            'application/zip',
            'application/vnd.ms-office',
        ));
});

$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array(
        'byMail' => 'in:Y',
        'file1' => 'uploadable',
        'file2' => 'uploadable',
        'file3' => 'uploadable',
    ),
    (array) Lang::get('errors.upload')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, wanted to validate some additional MIME types, but didn't want to lose Symfony's base validation.

I extended Symfony's validation by adding the following to AppService provider and using extended_mimes instead of mimes in my validation rules.

```
Validator::extend('extended_mimes', function($attr, $file, $parameters)
{
        // get the file's MIME type
        $mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $file);

        // get Symfony's guesser
        $guesser = new MimeTypeExtensionGuesser;

        // create bonus guesses
        $bonus_guesses = [
            'application/vnd.ms-office' => 'xls',
        ];
        $bonus_guess = isset($bonus_guesses[$mime]) ? $bonus_guesses[$mime] : null;

        // check whether we either hit a correct guess, or we make a hit in a bonus guess
        return in_array($guesser -> guess($mime), $parameters) || in_array($bonus_guess, $parameters);
});
```

Just add whatever you want to bonus guesses to set additional MIMEs and their extensions.

You need to include Validator and Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeExtensionGuesser at the top of AppServiceProvider.